# Why does the Stefan-Boltzmann Law contain no information about the distance from the radiating body?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

The Stefan–Boltzmann law states that the power radiated per unit area of a black body is equal to:

$$ \frac{dP}{dA} = \sigma \cdot T^4 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left[\frac{W}{m^{2}}\right] $$

This power per unit area is radiated through EM Waves because of the motion of the charge carriers due to the non-zero absolute temperature $T$.

Hence, my questions are:

1.) **How can the value of $\frac{dP}{dA}$ be independent from the radial distance $r$ from the radiating body?** I've seen people applying this law to find out the power per unit area at a generic distance from the radiating body.

2.) **The quantity $\frac{dP}{dA}$ has the same unit of measurement of the [Poynting Vector Magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector)**. The last one describes the radiated power per unit area of an EM wave. Which is the relationship between these two quantities. I'm not sure they are exactly equal because:

- Again, the Poynting Vector decays as $\frac{1}{r^2}$ in the far-field region, whilst $\frac{dP}{dA}$ does not appear to decay.
- The Poynting Vector Magnitude maybe refers to a single wavelength, whilst $\frac{dP}{dA}$ to the whole spectrum of radiated wavelengths. But, can we say $\frac{dP}{dA}$ is the sum of all the Poynging vectors of each radiated wavelength?

3)**Why is $\frac{dP}{dA}$ commonly referred as *thermal power per unit area*? *It is just power per unit area***. Then, if the receiving body is purely resistive, it will become heat. If it is reflective or inductive/capacitive, it won't become heat.

Comment: It is the power *emitted* per uit area; not the power received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sigma T^4$ is the amount of energy the surface of a black body emits per square meter per second. The total energy emitted by a spherical black body with radius R per second is therefore $4\pi R^2\sigma T^4$. The energy flux at distance $r$ is thus $\frac{4\pi R^2\sigma T^4}{4\pi r^2} = \frac{R^2}{r^2}\sigma T^4$ so it *does* depend on r.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1) and the first part of 2): The area increases with distance. Therefore, the absolute power (dP) which you measure per $cm^2$ radial area decreases with increasing radius.

Comment: But, if dA increases with distance (whilst dP is the same), why does the ratio dP/dA equals a constant value (non-dependent on the distance)?

Comment: In your comment, "dP is the same" is wrong.

Comment: The $A$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann law is the area of the *emitting surface*. It is not the area of the detector.